# How can I disable cache in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to disable cache in puppeteer, can anyone please tell me how I can do so? I found this `page.setCacheEnabled(enabled)` but I couldn't understand how to use the same.

I am aware that the browser is launched without cache or cookies but in my case the browser is always running in the background thus need a different solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the puppeteer docs you can use `await page.setCacheEnabled(enabled)`

This was added back in December. [See Git Hub issue #1609](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/1609)

If you look at the [commit changes](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/1609/commits/7c249b3b8f41b53b375bdf029309931b10b0f9e4) there is a test e.g.

```
await page.goto(SOMEURL);

await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
expect(responses.get('one-style.css').fromCache()).toBe(true);

await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
expect(responses.get('one-style.css').fromCache()).toBe(false);
```

Answer (score 22):

If you want session isolation, there is also: 

    `const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();`

which will give you a fresh start on each page.

Comment: Hey this was a really good tip! I needed to start every page with isolated cookies

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`cdpSession.send()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#cdpsessionsendmethod-params) to disable cache:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

await client.send('Network.setCacheDisabled', {
  cacheDisabled: true,
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the more readable [`page.setCacheEnabled()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcacheenabledenabled):

```
await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Every browser launch starts with clean HTTP cache and without any cookies.

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch(); // no cache, no cookies!
```

You may try this. For my cases without cache , i am using this.

Comment: Hello , I am aware of this but in my case the browser is always running in the background so I want a way to disable cache.

Comment: I didn't find an expert solution for this, by another way i have put a cron to to clear catalogs at certain interval of time from /var/lib/puppet/client_data/catalog/. its not much advisable at your case.

Comment: if you are using `userDataDir` then this would not work.