# How to cache file with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to know how I can cache a file with puppeteer, so I don't have to load it again when the script starts, assuming I have this script:

```
async function run () {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto("https://www.amazon.com/");
 browser.close();
}
run();
```

Well, if I wanted to save the html so it wouldn't be necessary to load it again, how would I do it?  I researched and found [How can I disable cache in puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761951/how-can-i-disable-cache-in-puppeteer) but I didn't find many details neither in the answer, nor in the question, could someone explain to me how to save the html in cache for example?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Puppeteer emulates browser's behavior so it cache resources the same way as browser does.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Drag13 Well, I'm not sure if it stores the html anymore and if for example I have a javascript file that is being referenced in the html (javascript file separate from html), how could I save javascript files that are separate from html to be used again  without having to load it again

Comment: @Drag13 Well assuming you want to cache this `test.js` file to be used again without having to reload it, how can I do this?  I want to keep the file saved, to simply be used when you need it, without having to reload it

Comment: In case you are doing tests during one session and you don't disable cache manually and cache headers are present in your static resources it will be done automatically, the same way browser do. In case you want to cache resources in between launches - you have to "warm" (load it once) the page before tests to get resources cached

Comment: @Drag13 I believe that the html for example is not cached, because if I try to access any page online and then stop running the script and try to open the same page but offline the page doesn't load, and if it doesn't load it isn't stored  in cache correct?

Comment: Not exactly. To work offline you need to implement service worker that will intercept the request and return it from cache. Because even if you index.html is in cache - browser will still try to reach server to verify if it is not expired. 
So if you need to make it work offline - use Service Worker. But there are some pitfalls on this step (exactly with caching and invalidating the cache) so read manuals first.

Comment: @Drag13 Ok, so my idea in this case is to use the cached html to access offline, but I need the external files of this html such as `https://www.anythink.com/test.js` to be  working, do you think it's possible to do this?

Comment: Using Service Worker you can be completely offline and everything including the 3rd party resources will work. In another case server should be reachable to make it work even with cache. But if you have concerns only about the speed - don't worry. Cached resources that are not expired will be not fetched completely, just checked expiration and then taken from the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puppeteer uses Chrome (or FireFox) browser under the hood, so in case:

- This is not the first visit (cache filled)
- Resources has proper cache headers and not expired (cache-control, etc.)
- You didn't disable cache manually using

```js
await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
await pageSession.send('Network.setCacheDisabled', { cacheDisabled: true });
```

Resources will be already cached and you don't need to do anything manually.

However, if you want to do testing on cached page, you will need to warm it up simply pre visiting it before tests, like in the example:

```js
async function warmingBrowser(url: URL, pageInstance: Page) {
    await pageInstance.goto(url.href, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await pageInstance.close();
}
```

The code is taken from the [perfrunner](https://github.com/Drag13/perfrunner/blob/06346b7852d6615d458340e6a2a4b22b84db7c52/packages/perfrunner-core/src/profiler/profiler.ts)

In case you want to make it work completely offline - Puppeteer will not help with that, you need to implement your own caching strategy using the [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).

But there are some pitfalls on this step (exactly with caching and invalidating the cache) so be aware.

Answer (score 4):

You can use setRequestInterception and respond manually what you want:

```js
page.setRequestInterception(true)
page.on('request', (req) => {
if (req.url() == 'your_url' && <there is a cached value>) {
   return request.respond({ status: 200, body: <your_cached_body>, <your_cached_headers> });
}
});
```

And cache requests if not already saved using:

```js
page.on('requestfinished', async (request) => { 
if (request.url() != <check if already available in cached value>) { 
   // Save in cached value
}
```

Comment: Setting request interception to `true` disables native cache.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a problem. For implementation your own caching mechanism, you will need around 10 lines of code and a db.